# List<T>.ForEach vs. custom IEnumerable<T> extension

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

Say I have a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
   ...
}
```

and a webservice method that returns an `IEnumerable<MyClass>`

The consumer of the webservice defines some method:

```
public void DoSomething(MyClass myClass)
{
   ...
}
```

Now, the consumer can call `DoSomething` on the result of the webservice method in two ways:

```
var result = // web service call

foreach(var myClass in result)
{
   DoSomething(myClass);
}
```

or:

```
var result = // web service call

result.ToList().ForEach(DoSomething);
```

Needless to say I much prefer the second way since it is much shorter and more expressive (once you get used to the syntax, which I have).

Now, the web service method only exposes an `IEnumerable<MyClass>`, but it actually returns a `List<MyClass>` which (AFAIK) means that the actual serialized object is still a `List<T>`. However, I have found (using reflector) that the Linq method `ToList()` makes a copy of all the objects in the `IEnumerable<T>` regardless of the actual runtime type (in my opinion, it could just have casted the argument to a `List<T>` if it already was one).

This obviously has some performance overhead, especially for large list (or lists of large objects).

So what can I do to overcome this problem, and why is there no `ForEach` method in Linq?

By the way, his question is vaguely related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297100/wcf-operationcontract-which-generic-collection-type-should-i-expose).

Comment: `ToList()` does not make a copy of the objects unless they are value type. Instead, it creates a list with the same references, which allows a modification of the original list when the loop is still active (in some situation you may want this). It also allows the use of a variable delegate, in case the `DoSomething` action depends on something else or is an argument, and that is probably the case where `ForEach` makes sense - although you could do without.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use 2 methods.  One iterates the list, one works with lazy eval.  I use them as the situation defines.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ForEachChained<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            action(item);
            yield return item;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> ForEachImmediate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            action(item);
        }
        return source;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can write an extension method but there are [good reasons](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) why ForEach is not implemented on `IEnumerable<T>`. The second example

```
result.ToList().ForEach(DoSomething);
```

copies the IEnumerable into a List (unless it's already a List, I assume) so you're better off just iterating the IEnumerable with good old `foreach(var r in result) {}`.

Addendum:

For me, the key point of Eric Lippert's article is that adding ForEach has no benefit and adds some potential pitfalls:

> The second reason is that doing so
>   adds zero new representational power
>   to the language. Doing this lets you
>   rewrite this perfectly clear code:
>
> foreach(Foo foo in foos){ statement
>   involving foo; }
>
> into this code:
>
> foos.ForEach((Foo foo)=>{ statement
>   involving foo; });
>
> which uses almost exactly the same
>   characters in slightly different
>   order. And yet the second version is
>   harder to understand, harder to debug,
>   and introduces closure semantics,
>   thereby potentially changing object
>   lifetimes in subtle ways.

Comment: +1 for linking to Eric Lippert's definitive post on why there is no ForEach in Linq

Comment: That is correct, LINQ was designed for querying, not for iteration

Comment: I agree with the Eric's analysis of his example, but I think he neglects this: `foos.ForEach(SomeMethod)`. There are no closure semantics to speak of, and in my opinion it's actually easier to read and more concise than a `foreach` loop when all you want to do is call a method for each item in a list. Because of the clear benefit and lack of significant drawbacks, I went ahead and implemented my own extension method, and I'll never give it up!

Answer (score 5):

I would prefer this:-

```
foreach (var item in result.ToList())
{
   DoSomething(item);
}
```

Its a much clearer idiom, it says collect a list of stuff together **then** do something important that may change the state of the application.  Its old school but it works and is actually more understandable to a wider audience.

Comment: I agree with the foreach but why convert to a List if it's already IEnumerable?

Comment: @Jamie:  The `ToList` is there because its in the original question. There are times when that is necessary.  If for example the `DoSomething` represents an operation that removes items from a collection that is the ultimate source of the `IEnumerable` then you'd likely get an exception if you don't include the `ToList`.  Of course if you are happy that `DoSomething` isn't going to do that then most likely it isn't necessary.

Comment: You can also put a breakpoint on the `ForEach` delegate parameter, so debugging is as easy in either case.

Comment: @RedGlyph: Good point, I've removed Brian's edit of my answer.  Am I off message to be slightly irritated with someone adding content like that to my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` like so:

```
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (T t in enumerable)
            action(t);
    }
```

Such a method is not present in Linq, because Linq is basically meant for queries, not for simple iterations.

Also, note that when using an actual `List<T>` instance, 
the extension method will not be called because instance methods have precedence over extension methods when they share signature.

The following code, for example, would not invoke the extension method:

```
 var l = new List<MyClass>();
 l.Add(new MyClass());
 l.ForEach(DoSomething);
```

Whereas the following would:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> l = new List<MyClass>(new []{new MyClass()});
l.ForEach(DoSomething);
```

Comment: Honestly, I really dislike this.  It's not wrong, so I'm not going to downvote it, but you're conflating functional (closure) and imperative semantics here and it can easily lead to unexpected, hard-to-debug problems or at best poor readability.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own extension method ToList(this List theList){return theList;} and then avoid the overhead. Since your extension method is the most specific one it will be called, not the one on IEnumerable

Answer (score -2):

If you decide to do this via an extension method, I'd call it ForAll instead of ForEach. This in order to use the same syntax as the [Parallel Extensions in .NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(VS.100).aspx) use:

```
var result = // web service call
result.AsParallel().ForAll(DoSomething);
```

Comment: Why call it `ForAll`, introducing confusion with the parallelized version, when there's already an existing Framework method `ForEach` with this exact semantics (just a different type)?